# Planes, Intercepts, and Minimzation (MIT 18.02 Pset 4; 2F-3)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up this equation. Doing self-study, this is the only teacher I have when I feel stuck. Thanks!

"Consider all the planes passing through the point (2,1,1) and such that the intercepts on the three coordinate axes are all positive. For which of these planes is the product of the three intercepts the smallest? (Hint: take the plane in the form z=ax+by+c, where a and b are the independent variables.)"

Let's assume I understand the basics of minimization, so no need to work the problem through. I'm just having setting up the constraining equation to what it is (I think) I'm trying to minimize.

Here's where I'm at: I need to find $\min (abc)$ where $a, b, c$ are the x, y, and z intercepts of some plane that passes through (2,1,1). I tried constraining by $\frac 2a + \frac 1b + \frac 1c = 1$ ala the intercept form of a plane, but 1. it doesn't use their hint, 2. it doesn't use the fact $a,b,c > 0$, 3, and, sure enough, when I try to solve, I get values less than zero.

Comment: Start by writing the equation of a plane through $(2,1,1)$ in the form $z=ax+by+c$, for which you’ll have to solve for $c$ in terms of the independent variables $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Maybe I need more practice with planes, generally, but I don't understand how that gets me where I need to go with respect to the intercepts. Can you clarify a little?

Comment: It's a long answer. The calculus part the less, I'm affraid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folloing the hint, we assume the equation of the plane has the form $z=ax+by+c$. The plane’s three intercepts can be found by setting each pair of variables to zero in turn. Taking the $x$-intercept first, it occurs when $y=z=0$, which gives $ax+c=0$, or $x=-c/a$. Using the same technique for the other two intercepts produces $y=-c/b$ and $z=c$. The function to be minimized is then $f(a,b)=c^3/ab$.

The next step is to solve for $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. Plug the known point into the equation, producing $2a+b+c=1$, and solve for $c$. Now you have the objective function in terms of $a$ and $b$ only: $$f(a,b)={(1-2a-b)^3\over ab}.$$ This function has more than one critical point, but you should be able to use the condition that the three intercepts exist and are positive to reject the extraneous solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$\pi:z=ax+by+c$ The intercepts are $-c/a$, $-c/b$ and $c$. The function to minimize is $I=c^3/(ab)$

As the point $(2,1,1)$ belongs to $\pi$, $1=a·2+b+c$, or $c=1-2a-b$, Also $I=(1-2a-b)^3/(ab)$

As we want to find the min, the partial derivatives must vanish.

$$\begin{cases}
   \dfrac{\partial I}{\partial a}=\dfrac{-6(1-2a-b)^2a-(1-2a-b)^3}{a^2b}=0\\
   \dfrac{\partial I}{\partial b}=\dfrac{-3(1-2a-b)^2b-(1-2a-b)^3}{ab^2}=0
\end{cases}$$

For a quotient to be zero, the numerator must be zero

$$\begin{cases}
   -6(1-2a-b)^2a-(1-2a-b)^3=0\\
   -3(1-2a-b)^2b-(1-2a-b)^3=0
\end{cases}$$

Substracting the first to the second, $(1-2a-b)^2(6a-3b)=0$ Then $1-2a-b=0$ or $6a-3b=0$

We need only take $6a-3b=0$; $b=2a$ ($1-2a-b=0$ leads to the equations being indentically zero) substituting it in the second:

$-3(1-2b)^2b-(1-2b)^3=0\implies(1-2b)^2(-3b-(1-2b))=0\implies$

$\implies(1-2b)^2(-b-1)=0$

$(1-2b)^2$ leads to $b=1/2\;;a=1/4\;\text{and}\;c=0$ Nosense

So, $-b-1=0$. Looking backwards $a=-1/2$ and $c=1-2(-1/2)-(-1)=3$

The intercepts are $-c/a=-3/(-1/2)=6$, $-c/b=-3/(-1)=3$ and $c=3$

Comment: I'm looking at this very question a few years later.I'm just wondering how this all ties into minimizing the product of the three intercepts.

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach, you get:

$$c = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{2}{a} - \frac{1}{b}} = \frac{ab}{ab -a - 2b}$$

The product to be minimized by setting the gradient to zero:

$$abc = \frac{a^2b^2}{ab -a - 2b}$$

According to WolframAlpha, this expression [has a minimum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%20a%5E2*b%5E2%2F(a*b%20-%20a%20-%202*b)) $54$ at $a=6, b=3, c=3$

---

**Alternative solution:**
Resolving the plane equation to $a$ yields:

$$a = \frac{2}{1 - \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{c}} = \frac{2bc}{bc - b -c}$$

The product becomes:

$$abc = \frac{2b^2c^2}{bc - b - c}$$

This expression is symmetric in $b$ in $c$. Therefore, $b=c$ can be assumed for the minimum:

$$abc = \frac{2b^4}{b^2 - 2b} = \frac{2b^4}{b^2 - 2b} = = \frac{2b^3}{b - 2}$$

The derivative vanishes for $b=3$. This implies $c=3$ and $a=6$ as shown above.